# About pazy's book(semigroup) Thm 4.1 Abstract Cauchy Problem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For anyone who happens to have Pazy's book on hand,on page 104, it says

"Therefore T(t) can be extended to all of X by continuity.After this extension T(t) becomes a C0 semigroup on X"

I have no idea what this sentence means. Could you please elaborate on how you come to this conclusion?

Comment: Sorry Not Thm4.1,Thm4.1.3

Comment: You can edit the title of your question.

Comment: Without the book in hand, how can anyone know the context here, or even what $T(t)$ and $X$ are?